# Finding f(x) for a given integral of it for all real values except 0

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, curves

So I'm a calculus student who isn't that far along yet (about to end Calc II at uni) and I was looking at integrals in my spare time...

Basically my question is this:
$$
\int_0^af(x)dx =0.5
$$

Where a = all real numbers except 0 and I'm trying to find an answer to f(x)

The reason I thought of this is because $\int_0^1xdx=0.5$ and I was wondering if there was some sort of circle or circle-like thing (turns out there's no circle to describe this) or curve upon which all input x values resolve to have an integral of 0.5

This also might get hard as $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ should start to act weird, since the distance between x and 0 are super small... I wonder if this is even possible.

Also if you have time, I'd wanna find out if there's a generalizable method I can use to always find f(x) given any value (other than 0), not just 0.5

I also will specifically request that whatever answer I get be dumbed down to a college sophomore level. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

$\int_0^x f(t)\ dt = F(x)$ where $\frac {d}{dx} F(x) = f(x).$     This is the fundamental theorem of calculus.

If $F(x)$ is constant for all $x > 0$ then $f(x) = 0$ for all $x>0$